# Connection reset on Apple receipt validation (Java 8)

Tags: java, ios, security, java-8

I am using a Java server to validate Apple payment receipts with their [validation server](https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt). Around 50% of our requests fail with a "SocketException: connection reset", for valid receipts (trying again later succeeds).

I am not experiencing this behaviour with another server that is deployed on Java 7, but started experiencing this when deployed to Java 8.

I saw that the default TLS protocol changed in Java 8 from TLSv1 to TLSv1.2, so I tried to change the default protocol to use Java 7's default, but saw no improvements. This is the JVM property I used:

```
-Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1"
```

Any idea why I'm getting the error "SocketException: connection reset" around half the time?

Thanks!

[UPDATE]

I managed to get debug and ssl logs for a failed request:

```
DEBUG [2017-03-02 00:35:37,586]     org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager: Connection request: [route: {s}->https://buy.itunes.apple.com:443][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 50; total allocated: 1 of 2000]
DEBUG [2017-03-02 00:35:37,586] org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager: Connection leased: [id: 4][route: {s}->https://buy.itunes.apple.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 50; total allocated: 1 of 2000]
DEBUG [2017-03-02 00:35:37,586] org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient: Stale connection check
dw-66 - POST /v1/reqrep, setSoTimeout(1) called
dw-66 - POST /v1/reqrep, handling exception:     java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
dw-66 - POST /v1/reqrep, setSoTimeout(15000) called
dw-66 - POST /v1/reqrep, setSoTimeout(15000) called
DEBUG [2017-03-02 00:35:37,590] org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies: CookieSpec selected: ignoreCookies
DEBUG [2017-03-02 00:35:37,590] org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache: Auth cache not set in the context
DEBUG [2017-03-02 00:35:37,590] org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestTargetAuthentication: Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
DEBUG [2017-03-02 00:35:37,590] org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestProxyAuthentication: Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
DEBUG [2017-03-02 00:35:37,590] org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient: Attempt 1 to execute request
DEBUG [2017-03-02 00:35:37,590] org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection: Sending request: POST /verifyReceipt HTTP/1.1
DEBUG [2017-03-02 00:35:37,590] org.apache.http.wire:  >> "POST /verifyReceipt HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
DEBUG [2017-03-02 00:35:37,590] org.apache.http.wire:  >> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded[\r][\n]"
DEBUG [2017-03-02 00:35:37,590] org.apache.http.wire:  >> "Content-Length: 6839[\r][\n]"
DEBUG [2017-03-02 00:35:37,590] org.apache.http.wire:  >> "Host: buy.itunes.apple.com[\r][\n]"
DEBUG [2017-03-02 00:35:37,590] org.apache.http.wire:  >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
DEBUG [2017-03-02 00:35:37,590] org.apache.http.wire:  >> "[\r][\n]"
DEBUG [2017-03-02 00:35:37,590] org.apache.http.headers: >> POST /verifyReceipt HTTP/1.1
DEBUG [2017-03-02 00:35:37,590] org.apache.http.headers: >> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
DEBUG [2017-03-02 00:35:37,590] org.apache.http.headers: >> Content-Length: 6839
DEBUG [2017-03-02 00:35:37,591] org.apache.http.headers: >> Host: buy.itunes.apple.com
DEBUG [2017-03-02 00:35:37,591] org.apache.http.headers: >> Connection: Keep-Alive
dw-66 - POST /v1/reqrep, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 179
dw-66 - POST /v1/reqrep, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 6863
dw-66 - POST /v1/reqrep, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
%% Invalidated:  [Session-505, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
dw-66 - POST /v1/reqrep, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
dw-66 - POST /v1/reqrep, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 26
dw-66 - POST /v1/reqrep, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
dw-66 - POST /v1/reqrep, called closeSocket()
dw-66 - POST /v1/reqrep, called close()
dw-66 - POST /v1/reqrep, called closeInternal(true)
DEBUG [2017-03-02 00:35:37,595] org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection: Connection 0.0.0.0:59028<->17.173.66.179:443 closed
DEBUG [2017-03-02 00:35:37,595] org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient: Closing the connection.
DEBUG [2017-03-02 00:35:37,595] org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection: Connection 0.0.0.0:59028<->17.173.66.179:443 closed
ERROR [2017-03-02 00:35:37,600] com.spaceape.http.client.HttpClient$$anon$1: http retry for it. executionCount=1
! java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
<ommitted stack trace>
INFO  [2017-03-02 00:35:37,601] org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://buy.itunes.apple.com:443: Connection reset
DEBUG [2017-03-02 00:35:37,603] org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient: Connection reset
! java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
<ommitted stack trace>
INFO  [2017-03-02 00:35:37,604] org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient: Retrying request to {s}->https://buy.itunes.apple.com:443
DEBUG [2017-03-02 00:35:37,604] org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient: Reopening the direct connection.
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
DEBUG [2017-03-02 00:35:37,609] org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator: Connecting to buy.itunes.apple.com:443
dw-66 - POST /v1/reqrep, setSoTimeout(15000) called
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
...
```

After which the SSL connection is successfully reopened and the validation takes place.
The specific bit of the log above where the connection is reset is:

```
dw-66 - POST /v1/reqrep, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 179
dw-66 - POST /v1/reqrep, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 6863
dw-66 - POST /v1/reqrep, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
%% Invalidated:  [Session-505, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
dw-66 - POST /v1/reqrep, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
dw-66 - POST /v1/reqrep, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 26
dw-66 - POST /v1/reqrep, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
dw-66 - POST /v1/reqrep, called closeSocket()
dw-66 - POST /v1/reqrep, called close()
dw-66 - POST /v1/reqrep, called closeInternal(true)
DEBUG [2017-03-02 00:35:37,595] org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection: Connection 0.0.0.0:59028<->17.173.66.179:443 closed
DEBUG [2017-03-02 00:35:37,595] org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient: Closing the connection.
DEBUG [2017-03-02 00:35:37,595] org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection: Connection 0.0.0.0:59028<->17.173.66.179:443 closed
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

We are currently having the same problem. If we call this command about 5-10 times from our server:

```
openssl s_client -connect buy.itunes.apple.com:443 -tls1_2
```

it will eventually simply hang with no response. And presumably the java *SocketException* (that we're also seeing in our logs) is happening because it reaches the timeout. One of Apple's validation servers having problems maybe?